# iphone c++ xcode 4.0 ios 4.3

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, ios, xcode4

i have an iphone project which was perfectly running with xcode 3.2 and ios 4.1. inside these project i am using c++ and different libraries (e.g opensurf, opencv, tesseract).. when i updated to xcode 4.0 and ios 4.3 it was not working anymore.. it crashing inside the libraries.. e.g. in the opensurf library:

```
void FastHessian::interpolateStep(int r, int c, ResponseLayer *t, ResponseLayer *m, ResponseLayer *b, 
                                  double* xi, double* xr, double* xc )
{
  CvMat* dD, * H, * H_inv, X;
  double x[3] = { 0 };

  dD = deriv3D( r, c, t, m, b );
  H = hessian3D( r, c, t, m, b );
  H_inv = cvCreateMat( 3, 3, CV_64FC1 );
  cvInvert( H, H_inv, CV_SVD );  // Program received signal: "SIGABRT"
  cvInitMatHeader( &X, 3, 1, CV_64FC1, x, CV_AUTOSTEP );
  cvGEMM( H_inv, dD, -1, NULL, 0, &X, 0 );

  cvReleaseMat( &dD );
  cvReleaseMat( &H );
  cvReleaseMat( &H_inv );

  *xi = x[2];
  *xr = x[1];
  *xc = x[0];
}
```

malloc: *** error for object 0x20000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

any ideas? i think i am missing one or more settings in the build configuration?

Comment: which compiler is it set to? I believe LLVM has limited support of objective-c++

Comment: Hey Ben, did you manage to figure this one out? It currently has me stumped as well.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction in the link to trace and solve malloc related issues by adding the breakpoint http://www.drooljunkie.com/2010/03/beginning-iphone-app-dev-issues-part-3-double-free-errors/  hope this helps

Comment: i already tried it! but its completely new in xcode4 and it is not stopping at any meaningful point..

Comment: Same for me. This is why Xcode is #1 in my hate hall of shame.